# Where to edit buld/run task in VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Whenever I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> in VS Code, it runs the following for a C file:

```
[Running] cd "/Users/david/Desktop/cparser/" && gcc main.c -o main && "/Users/david/Desktop/cparser/"main
```

Where can I modify this behavior? It shows the default 'build task' for C as using `clang`, but that is not actually what happens when I run it. Where can I find out what 'runs' when I press Cmd-R and how to modify that?

Here is what Shift-Cmd-B gives me:

```
> Executing task: /usr/bin/gcc -g /Users/david/Desktop/cparser/new6.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O2 -o /Users/david/Desktop/cparser/new6 <
```

But doing Shift-R still gives me the old stuff (without the `-W` stuff):

```
[Running] cd "/Users/david/Desktop/cparser/" && gcc new6.c -o new6 && "/Users/david/Desktop/cparser/"new6
[Done] exited with code=4 in 0.062 seconds
```

---

Perhaps another way to ask this is, which folders should I grep to get the file that may contain this so I can edit it?

```
$ grep -ir '&& gcc' ./
```

Comment: Use [tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks).

Comment: @sanitizedUser I've updated the build task and that now runs what I want it but cmd-r still doesn't use that default build. Where do I modify the 'run' task? See updated question.

Comment: You should probably check your keybindings settings: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-rules (also for me Cmd+R is "reload editor", so I assume you or some plugin has changed that binding)

Comment: @UnholySheep I mean the "Run code" -- https://imgur.com/a/DVbrfnw

Comment: Is that from the Code Runner extension? AFAIK VSCode doesn't have this command by default (and for me it's also on a different shortcut) - if it is from the extension then you should check the extension settings for it (there should be options to change the command in the "Executor Map")

Comment: @UnholySheep yup that seems to be it: `code-runner.executorMap ` ... but where can I find that file?

Comment: It's not a file, you change or add it in your "settings.json" file (in this case you probably want to change it in the workspace settings file?) - the VSCode editor should offer autocomplete for the settings.json file to help you make the changes

Comment: @UnholySheep all right, that was a bit tricky -- but I got it (posted an answer), thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the Code Runner extension. You can modify it as follows (depending on the version of `code-runner` installed):

```
# ~/.vscode/extensions/formulahendry.code-runner-0.11.2/package.json

"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "default": {
         "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O2 -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
    }
}
```